# Книга по инструментарию С++. Есть ли такая?

Tags: c++, книги, cmake, clang

Краткая предыстория. На одном из онлайн-курсов по C++ я натолкнулся на сочетание cmake + clang + eclipse. Автор курса уделил этому делу времени 5 минут и сказал, что это всё "ийзи настраивается" и поехал читать курс по C++. Для меня, пользователя windows, всё оказалось не "ийзи". После 2-3 недель, что я зарылся в различных сайтах, я так и не смог наладить работу этой системы. Если верно помню, то clang ни в какую работать не хотел и выдавал ошибки, адекватное описание которым я не находил. В итоге я смог запустить свой код каким-то заднепроходным путём, через консоль Visual Studio. Но совершенно не было ощущения, что я что-то понял, и что вообще работают те программы, что я пытался использовать, а не встроенные в VS инструменты. А скорее дело было в последнем. Я как не понимал, как это всё работает, так и не понимаю.

Вопрос такой. Есть ли книга, которая рассказывала бы про инструментарий и про правильную организацию работы с ним вокруг именно C++? Касаясь основных вопросов компиляции, организации кода, этапов, чтобы более или менее начать всё это(что, откуда, чего, куда, зачем) понимать, а не просто надеяться, что среда разработки сама всё знает и сделает как надо. Чтобы банально понимать, как работают clang и cmake с кодом, что ты пишешь. Желательно на РЯ. Не то, чтобы я не мог читать на английском. Но мне хочется в итоге поглубже и по подробнее вникнуть в тему и разобраться. Для этого нужно в голове создать какую-то начальную базу знаний от которой потом отталкиваться. Делать это на английском крайне неудобно мозгу.

Можете меня сориентировать по этому вопросу? Заранее, спасибо.

P.S. Все, кто считают, что в IT АЯ знать на столько важно, что не могут протий мимо и промолчать, начиная утверждать, какой я дундук, что пользуюсь РЯ. Ради бога, пройдите мимо, я уже столько наслушался вас. Иизвините за бугурт. Ответ на этот вопрос поискиваю с начала прошлого года. В вк задавал в разных группах, и на сайтах вопросов. И везде одно и то же - народ начинает пояснять за значимость английского. А я с этой значимостью и не спорил никогда. Мне просто нужно хорошенько вникнуть в тему. Мне легче делать это на родном языке. Документацию читать могу спокойно на английском. Но в глубинную философию чего-либо - не могу пока.

Comment: Как бы у этих инструментов имеется документация, иногда даже неплохая. RTFM, как говорится. А вот про "правильную организацию работы" - это вам вряд ли кто расскажет. Разве что какие-нибудь неадекваты набегут, с криками типа "IDE - отстой", "cmake - это стандарт" или "только vim, только хардкор". Плюрализм же. Но в качестве отправной точки можете ознакомиться с https://dev.chromium.org/developers

Comment: не совсем понятно о каком инструментарии вы говорите когда задаете вопрос: о том как настроить связку cmake + clang + eclipse, о которой писали выше? Или вас интересует работа именно инструментов: компилятора, make, cmake и тул, которые помагают в сопровождении и огранизации проекта (не только с++)

Comment: сломал голову, пытаясь понять, что такое РЯ/АЯ. А для меня даже русский - чужой, но ничего, как то разобрался, хотя по началу было очень сложно. Лучше перестать ныть и начать делать. У всех вначале не получалось. я тоже свою первую программу компилировал несколько месяцев - интернета не было, документации тоже. Угадывал.

Comment: А никто не знает того, что вы просите. Даже на АЯ. Во всяком случае, у меня такое стойкое убеждение. Обычно такая настройка большинством людей делается кое-как, с матом и чертыханиями, а потом, когда всё работает, о ней забывают.

Comment: cmake + clang + eclipse это худшая сборка из всех возможных. cmake, которым пользуются только от того, что выбора особо нет. clang компилятор не особо хороший. И eclipse самая баганутая IDE из всех что я встречал. Возьми обычный вижуал, и делай в нём, если очень хочется то с cmake.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков А чем плох шланг? *"Есть ли книга, которая рассказывала бы про инструментарий"* Вы не про книгу спрашивайте, а лучше покажите нам конкретные ошибки, которые у вас были.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков Нуу. У него и плюсы есть: * собирает заметно быстрее GCC, иногда в разы; * умеет использовать стандартные библиотеки GCC и MSVC и совместим с ними по флажкам командной строки; * предоставляет библиотеки для парсинга С/С++, которые очень любят использовать в разных IDE; * кросс-компилировать под любую поддерживаемую платформу можно просто добавив флажок, не пересобирая весь компилятор; ...

Comment: @HolyBlackCat С++ изначально кроссплатформенный, чтоб он не собрался в другой платформе, нужно что-то нето заюзать: windows.h например. Парсить то можно, но не С++20 ибо его он не жрёт покачто. И быстрее не значит лучше, еа релиз мне же нужна топ производительность, а не скорость компиляции.

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch да вот сам пытаюсь понятью... С какого бока подступиться, чтобы было правильнее и попонятнее в голове уложить. Бесконечные курсы по самому C++ и книги надоели. Ибо каждый раз сталкиваясь с какой-то проблемой или ошибкой - начинается неразумное гугление по кодам и error меседжам. Хотелось бы более комплексно подходить к решению задач и проблем, с пониманием, а не через открываение подряд ссылок, пока не наткнёшься на инструцкцию, где кто-то написал что и куда прокликать, дабы решить проблему. Ибо понималки от этого не становится больше ни на йоту (( P.S. Всем сяб за ответы.

Comment: @НикитаСамоуков *"С++ изначально кроссплатформенный"* Я не про это. :) Вот например, у меня на убунте стоит кланг, и я могу компилировать им и под линукс, и под винду (используя хедеры/библиотеки/... от MinGW). А с GCC такое не прокатит, его нужно ставить в двух вариантах.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat сочувствую, на линукс же и вижуал не ставится...

Answer (score 2):

Для начала конечно же посоветую перейти на Linux, хотя бы поднять его на виртуальной машине (Oracle VirtualBox, если вдруг не знаешь). Сам использую Clion от JetBrains, если пройти несколько уроков на Stepik можно получить лицензию.
cmake + clang + Clion - связка "из коробки", если устанавливать на Linux.
Советую книги http://www.stolyarov.info/books , распространяются бесплатно. Читать их лучше по порядку.
По своему опыту понял, что лучше смотреть как устроены репозитории популярных проектов на С++ на GitHub.

Comment: Зачем пару недель возится, пытаясь заставляя линукс работать и разбираясь с этим cmake и clion? Какой вообще смысл кодить на линуксе? Чтоб при утечке в программе комп намертво вис и только REISUB работал? Помню как-то попробовал IDEA от JetBrains, это нечто стабильно крашилось раз в 5-10 минут, может clion и получше, но врятли.